# Elasticsearch Deduplication

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

I have a collection of documents where each document looks like

```
    {
        "_id": ... ,
        "Author": ...,
        "Content": ....,
        "DateTime": ...
    }
```

I would like to issue one query to the collection so that I get in response the oldest document from each author. I am considering using a terms aggregation but when I do that I get a list of buckets, being the unique Author values, telling me nothing about which of their documents is the oldest. Furthermore, that approach requires a subsequent call to ES, which is undesirable.

Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what does your query look like as of now? whats the output and whats the expected output?

Comment: The answer below by @jaspreet is probably to cleanest answer. For completion sake, your approach with the terms aggregations would also work if you add a [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) inside of your terms aggregation, however it's less clean and probably more expensive than the collapse option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html) in elastic search.

It will return top 1 record per author sorted on DateTime

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "collapse": {
    "field": "Author.keyword"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "DateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index83",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "e1QwrnABAWOsYG7tvNrB",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Author" : "b",
          "Content" : "ADSAD",
          "DateTime" : "2019-03-11"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "Author.keyword" : [
            "b"
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1552262400000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index83",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "elQwrnABAWOsYG7to9oS",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "Author" : "a",
          "Content" : "ADSAD",
          "DateTime" : "2019-03-10"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "Author.keyword" : [
            "a"
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1552176000000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

EDIT 1:

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "collapse": {
    "field": "Author.keyword"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "DateTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": 
         {
           "authors": {
                       "terms": {
                                "field": "Author.keyword", "size": 10 }, 
                       "aggs": {
                                "doc_count": { "value_count": { "field": 
                                                "Author.keyword"
                                             }
                                 }
                           }
                     }
             }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to determine how many elements were discovered / omitted when collapsing?  That is, if there were 10 posts by 'Author_A' and only the first one is returned, can I also get the count '10' to be returned somewhere?

Comment: terms aggregation with value_count sub aggregation will return count of all documents under author "aggs": {
        "authors": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Author.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "doc_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "Author.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

Comment: Thanks!  I have implemented that.  Looks like it takes two calls to Elasticsearch.  Is it possible to (1) do this in one call to ES, or (2) to include doc_count in the collapse response, or (3) exploit the Collapsable (Inner) Results somehow?

Comment: aggs and query can be run together. Aggregation run on documents returned in query. I have updated answer in EDIT 1

Comment: Thanks.  Without disturbing which result comes back from the collapsed group, how could I also sort the results being returned to the user on another field?  I am worried that just appending to the `sort` list will alter the within-group sorting and only change which result comes back from the collapsing, without changing the ordering of the results that come back.

Comment: collapsing returns top document per collapse key so change in sorting will lead to change in documents returned in collapse key. You can try out on actual data and check. Documents can also be returned in terms aggregation using top_hits https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way of doing it directly with one call to Elasticsearch. Fortunately, there's a [nice article on Elastic Blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-documents-in-elasticsearch) showing some methods of doing it.

One these methods is [using logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lessons-handling-duplicates) to remove duplicates. Other method include using a Python script that can be found on [this github repository](https://github.com/alexander-marquardt/deduplicate-elasticsearch):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import hashlib
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(["localhost:9200"])
dict_of_duplicate_docs = {}
# The following line defines the fields that will be
# used to determine if a document is a duplicate
keys_to_include_in_hash = ["CAC", "FTSE", "SMI"]
# Process documents returned by the current search/scroll
def populate_dict_of_duplicate_docs(hits):
    for item in hits:
        combined_key = ""
        for mykey in keys_to_include_in_hash:
            combined_key += str(item['_source'][mykey])
        _id = item["_id"]
        hashval = hashlib.md5(combined_key.encode('utf-8')).digest()
        # If the hashval is new, then we will create a new key
        # in the dict_of_duplicate_docs, which will be
        # assigned a value of an empty array.
        # We then immediately push the _id onto the array.
        # If hashval already exists, then
        # we will just push the new _id onto the existing array
        dict_of_duplicate_docs.setdefault(hashval, []).append(_id)
# Loop over all documents in the index, and populate the
# dict_of_duplicate_docs data structure.
def scroll_over_all_docs():
    data = es.search(index="stocks", scroll='1m',  body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    # Get the scroll ID
    sid = data['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
    # Before scroll, process current batch of hits
    populate_dict_of_duplicate_docs(data['hits']['hits'])
    while scroll_size > 0:
        data = es.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll='2m')
        # Process current batch of hits
        populate_dict_of_duplicate_docs(data['hits']['hits'])
        # Update the scroll ID
        sid = data['_scroll_id']
        # Get the number of results that returned in the last scroll
        scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
def loop_over_hashes_and_remove_duplicates():
    # Search through the hash of doc values to see if any
    # duplicate hashes have been found
    for hashval, array_of_ids in dict_of_duplicate_docs.items():
      if len(array_of_ids) > 1:
        print("********** Duplicate docs hash=%s **********" % hashval)
        # Get the documents that have mapped to the current hashval
        matching_docs = es.mget(index="stocks", doc_type="doc", body={"ids": array_of_ids})
        for doc in matching_docs['docs']:
            # In this example, we just print the duplicate docs.
            # This code could be easily modified to delete duplicates
            # here instead of printing them
            print("doc=%s\n" % doc)
def main():
    scroll_over_all_docs()
    loop_over_hashes_and_remove_duplicates()
main()
```

Comment: I don't think this question is about actually removing duplicates from the index.

Comment: Thanks!  Yea, I don't want to remove duplicates.  Much appreciated.